# JavaScript Function Invocation

Tags: javascript, function, this, invocation

I recently have started reading "JavaScript: good parts" and quoting one of the examples which I couldn't understand. I added a `test` function to the original example:

```
var add = function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
};

var myObject = {
    val: 0,
    increment: function(inc) {
        this.val += typeof inc == 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};

myObject.increment(12);
myObject.increment();
// till this line, the val is equal to 13

// function invocation
myObject.double = function() {
    var that = this;

    // inner function #1
    var helper = function() {
        that.val = add(that.val, that.val);
    };
    // inner function #2
    var test = function(){
        this.val = add(this.val, this.val);
    };

    helper();   // the val is equal to 26
    // test();  // the val is equal to 13
};
```

When I use `that` (`var that = this`) I am referring to `myObject`'s field, `val`. Also when I use this in my `test` function, I am referring to the same field in the same object, but the answer is different. any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this code in the browser console:

```
var obj = {
    val: 0
};

obj.func = function() {
    var that = this;

    console.log(this); // this refers to obj

    var test1 = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };

    test1(); // this refers to the global scope or window

    var test2 = function() {
        console.log(that);
    }

    test2(); // this or that refers to obj
}

obj.func();
```

In javascript, the keyword `this` can be pretty tricky. The value of `this` depends on how the function is invoked. The first `console.log` shows that `this` within `obj.func` refers to `obj`. For the next example, the keyword `this` is in the scope of the function `test1`. More importantly, `test1` is called differently than `obj.func`. Because `test1` is invoked without a dot to the left (as a property of an object), the keyword `this` actually refers to the global scope. You can think of the code running like `window.test1()`. The last example shows why the line `var that = this` is useful, it maintains the context to `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this` in

```
var test = function(){
   this.val = add(this.val, this.val);
};
```

`this` actually refers to `test`, not `myObject`, hence `this.val` is undefined and `this.val = add(this.val, this.val);` actually does nothing. This is why the val value is not changed.